# PageRemote Usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

First steps in Razor Pages with VS2022. Simple CRUD SQL based.

I would like to check if value in a text box already exist on database table but I began from check in a strings array.

Everything work fine if I use a string column but I'm unable to "transfer" this to database column.

My files:

Models\Customer.cs

```
namespace Test.Model
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        [PageRemote(PageHandler = "DescriptionExist", HttpMethod="get", ErrorMessage="Exist")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Pages\Customers\Create.cshtml

```
 <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Customer.CustomerID" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Customer.CustomerID" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Customer.CustomerID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Customer.Description" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Customer.Description" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Customer.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Pages\Customers\Create.cshtml.cs

```
public JsonResult OnGetDescriptionExist(string Description)
{
        var emails = new string[]
        {
            "text01",
            "secondtext",
            "someothertext"
        };

        if (emails.Contains(Description))
        {
            return new JsonResult(false);
        }
        
        return new JsonResult(true);
}
```

Event `OnGetDescriptionExist` is fired but `Description` is always null and therefore never return false.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards.

Massimo

**Update**

Changing

```
<input asp-for="Customer.Description" class="form-control" name=Description/>
```

I have the `Description` parameter with the textbox content.

Anyway, now I cannot save in both cases:

- if the value is found, nothing happen on click on create button. No message of value found
- if the value is not found on click on create button, textbox become empty and error message report that value is needed

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, you should be wanting to work with `Customer.Description`, the parameter you received in your handler should be an object like below:

```
public JsonResult OnGetDescriptionExist(Customer customer)
```

Below is my test code, you can refer to it:

Models\Customer.cs:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        [PageRemote(PageHandler = "DescriptionExist", HttpMethod = "get", ErrorMessage = "Exist")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Pages\Customers\Create.cshtml(Remove `name=Description`):

```
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Customer.CustomerID" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Customer.CustomerID" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Customer.CustomerID" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Customer.Description" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Customer.Description"  class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Customer.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Pages\Customers\Create.cshtml.cs:

```
public JsonResult OnGetDescriptionExist(Customer customer)
        {
            var emails = new string[]
            {
            "text01",
            "secondtext",
            "someothertext"
            };

            if (emails.Contains(customer.Description))
            {
                return new JsonResult(false);
            }

            return new JsonResult(true);
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost(Customer customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("Index");
            }
            return Page();
        }
```

Test Result:
[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

Url generate the parameter's name depends on your input name.

The reason why your url will generate the url like `https://localhost:7273/customer/create/?handler=DescriptionExist&Customer.Description=xx` is that `asp-for` would generate the name by default:

```
<input asp-for="Customer.Description"/>
```

Generate the html:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-remote="Exist" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Description" data-val-remote-type="get" data-val-remote-url="/Customers/Create?handler=DescriptionExist" data-val-required="The Description field is required." id="Customer_Description" name="Customer.Description" value="">
```

If you want to use `OnGetDescriptionExist(Customer someothername)`, please change your input to

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="someothername.Description" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="someothername.Description"  class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="someothername.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Chen, and many thanks for your fast reply. Seem that now, with your help, i reached my goal. One only clarification: Can you help me to understand why everything work with  **OnGetDescriptionExist(Customer customer)** but not work, as example, with **OnGetDescriptionExist(Customer someothername)** ? Just to understand better something that i missing...

Comment: Hi, @Max, I updated my answer,  can this answer help you solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @Chen. Thanks for your clarification. Now everything is clear and i can confirm that your answer solved my problem. I flagged the green to accept your answer. I'm new on this forum, so please let me know if that's is the last (and right) step for this post. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Chen and sorry if i'm again on this things.